# Find a line containing a certain string in a file

Tags: wpf, vb.net, file, file-io, streamreader

Trying to linear search a file to find a line that starts with a username (and a "," as it makes sure it is the whole username) in a file formatted as ",,," for each line.

I'm not sure how to do this so any help is appreciated.

```
    Dim lineCorrect As String = ""
    Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("Pass.txt")
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            If reader.ReadLine.StartsWith(tbUsernameLogIn.Text & ",") = True Then
                lineCorrect = reader.ReadLine
            Else
                reader.ReadLine()
            End If
        End While
    End Using
    If lineCorrect = "" Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Incorrect Login 1")
    Else
        'do something'
    End If
```

Comment: How big is this file? Could you load all the file in memory?

Comment: @Steve Currently, it contains 10 users but it could go all the way up to 80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple approach using the [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
Dim lineCorrect As String = ""
Dim userLine = tbUsernameLogIn.Text & ","
for Each line in File.ReadLines("Pass.txt")
    If line.StartsWith(userLine) Then
        lineCorrect = line
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If lineCorrect = "" Then
    Debug.WriteLine("Incorrect Login 1")
Else
    'do something'
End If
```

This allows you to enumerate all the lines in your file and exit the for each loop at the first occurence of the line searched. Also note a micro optimization. Keep the building of the string to check outside the loop (albeit probably the compiler will optimize that by itself)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
Dim lineCorrect As String
lineCorrect = File.ReadLines("Pass.txt") _
    .FirstOrDefault(Function(str) str.StartsWith(tbUsernameLogIn.Text & ","))
```